# Figma with JavaFX and custom components

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, figma, figma-api

## **Description**

With my team we are currently thinking to use Figma for the graphical part of out project, this way the designer will be able to make some modifications and get the components easily for the documentations.
Our project is using JavaFX 8, we are also using custom component inside the .fxml files.

## **Problem**

I saw that it is possible to create a project in Figma and then export it to JavaFX.
Howerver I did not saw the possibility to take an .fxml that already exist and import it into Figma.
The meaning of this is if a dev modify the .fxml, the designer can import the modifications in Figma.

## **Questions :**

- Is it possible to import an fxml to Figma ?
- Is it possible to use custom component (from .jar) inside Figma ?
- If it is not possible, is there alternative app that exist that I can look into ?

Comment: These seem like questions that should go to the Figma developers. Are you using `SceneBuilder`?

Comment: Yes, we are currently using scene builder but the designer in our team do not have any experience in coding and it would be easier to use another tool. That is why I was looking for advice here